java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oshi.SystemInfo
An error that the class named oshi.SystemInfo is not found when I use oshi.
This is a Java program in IDEA. I used maven to import oshi. But when I write SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo(), the SystemInfo and import oshi.SystemInfo; are red.
maven version: 3.6.2
springboot version: 3.4.0 or 2.6.5
java version: 17
this is code segment:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.CentralProcessor;
import oshi.hardware.Hardware AbstractionLayer;

@Service
public class CpuLoadMetricsService {

    SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();

    public double[] getCpuLoad() {
        HardwareAbstractionLayer hardware si.getHardware(); 
        CentralProcessor processor = hardware.getProcessor(); 
        double[] cpuLoad = processor.getProcessorCpuLoad(1000); 
        return cpuLoad;
    }
}

this is maven dependencies:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
            <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.5</version>
<!--            <version>4.4.2</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

these are error information:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.4.0)

2024-12-25T15:48:35.940+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] com.atguigu.oshi.OshiAppApplication      : Starting OshiAppApplication using Java 17.0.3.1 with PID 15424 (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\oshi-app\oshi-app\target\classes started by Administrator in C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\oshi-app\oshi-app)
2024-12-25T15:48:35.943+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] com.atguigu.oshi.OshiAppApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-12-25T15:48:36.625+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-12-25T15:48:36.637+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-12-25T15:48:36.638+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.33]
2024-12-25T15:48:36.679+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-25T15:48:36.680+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 700 ms
2024-12-25T15:48:36.727+08:00  WARN 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cpuLoadRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cpuLoadMetricsService': Error creating bean with name 'cpuLoadMetricsService' defined in file [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\oshi-app\oshi-app\target\classes\com\atguigu\oshi\service\CpuLoadMetricsService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.atguigu.oshi.service.CpuLoadMetricsService]: Constructor threw exception
2024-12-25T15:48:36.730+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-12-25T15:48:36.739+08:00  INFO 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-25T15:48:36.754+08:00 ERROR 15424 --- [oshi-app] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cpuLoadRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cpuLoadMetricsService': Error creating bean with name 'cpuLoadMetricsService' defined in file [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\oshi-app\oshi-app\target\classes\com\atguigu\oshi\service\CpuLoadMetricsService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.atguigu.oshi.service.CpuLoadMetricsService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1435) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.instantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1122) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1030) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:987) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at com.atguigu.oshi.OshiAppApplication.main(OshiAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cpuLoadMetricsService' defined in file [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\oshi-app\oshi-app\target\classes\com\atguigu\oshi\service\CpuLoadMetricsService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.atguigu.oshi.service.CpuLoadMetricsService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1333) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1218) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1568) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.atguigu.oshi.service.CpuLoadMetricsService]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:222) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oshi/SystemInfo
    at com.atguigu.oshi.service.CpuLoadMetricsService.<init>(CpuLoadMetricsService.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:196) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oshi.SystemInfo
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

I wonder if there is a big shot who can help me solve this problem.

As the primary maintainer of OSHI I guess I count as a "big shot".  Your Maven import looks correct (although you'll want a newer version of JNA (you need 5.13.0 at least, 5.14.0 was just released); but that's not relevant to this error).  This may simply be an issue with cached dependencies somewhere, either in your IDE or local maven repository.  Try doing a "clean" build.

How are you loading your dependencies?  The stack trace line ~[classes/:na] appears next to com.atguigu.oshi.service.CpuLoadMetricsService seems to imply possibly using a local JAR file instead of configuring your project to download dependencies from Maven
